# not responding application with system.io.file.writeAllBytes and System Ram

Tags: c#, filestream

I'm using the below file to convert a bytearray read from database into a pdf and there are around 31000 rows in the database, after around 200 rows that are converted the application crashes and not responds anymore, the ram goes up to the max. what exactly am I doing wrong?

```
var scanFile = (from t in _dbContext.ScanFiles
    where t.ID == scan.ID
    select t)
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (scanFile != null)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, scanFile.Data);
}
```

what can I do to avoid this problem with the ram and also the app crashing? thanks in advance

**EDIT:** changed my code to:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    fileStream.Write(scanFile.Data, 0, scanFile.Data.Length);
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

but still the same problem occurs.

Comment: Possible problems: you don't release resources, you keep the previous files (byte arrays?) in memory, so eventually your app consumes too much memory; or, one of the records is very very large and cannot be handled (not enough memory? "hanging application" might also be caused because your program is still processing, on the same thread as your "ui").

Comment: @Styxxy files are at most ~11MB so I assume not releasing the resources should be the reason?? How can I release the previous files from the memory? I've changed my code to use filestream and it's still the same.

Comment: Dont know if it makes any change but do you dispose the _dbContext between files?

Comment: @Magnus Nope, but I'll give it a try although I don't think that would be the cause of the problem, for now I'll try to put the whole process in a new thread and see if it makes any difference. thanks anyway

Comment: @Magnus disposing the _dbContext and reinitializing it lowered the memory in use a bit and i reached around 500 pdfs converted but the memory usage goes up after a while anyway, any idea how to keep the memory usage as low as possible ?